# Setting up Git for a single branch

Tags: git, branch, pull

I'm a complete newbie to Git. I have been using SVN forever but the new project I'm working on is stored in Git.

Now, I want to work on a single branch (let's name it 'mybranch') of that repository (let's say www.example.com/project.git). I've done the following:

```
git init

git clone -b mybranch --single-branch www.example.com/project.git
```

But when I do the following, it reloads the entire branch:

```
git pull www.example.com/project.git mybranch
```

which takes forever because there's already a lot in there. As far as I know, it should just update (fetch & merge) what I have. Like the svn command "update".

I've been skimming through tutorials and how-to's for days now and I have no idea what the heck is going on.

Thanks in advance!

-- Edit --
I get the following infos:

```
$ git branch -avv
```

returns nothing, just as `git remote -v` and `git branch -a`

```
$ git config --local -l
```

returns:

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
```

Comment: Can you show an output from `git remote -v` and `git branch -a`?

Comment: @StasMakarov Thorse return nothing, see edit in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a `git clone -b mybranch --single-branch`, you should have two things:

1. Your local checked out branch is linked to the remote upstream branch

   ```
   git br -avv
   * mybranch                 c228c1a [origin/mybranch]
   ```
2. Your repo should only fetch that branch

   ```
   git config --local -l
   remote.origin.url=appgit@git.intramundi.com:qoa/jardepsg.git
   remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/pkgjarcls:refs/remotes/origin/pkgjarcls
   branch.pkgjarcls.remote=origin
   branch.pkgjarcls.merge=refs/heads/pkgjarcls
   ```

In that case, you should need only

```
git pull
```

That would fetch and merge only your branch.

Comment: Thanks for your time. 'git br -avv' returns nothing, 'git config' etc. gives me something that looks just wrong. I edited the question above.

Comment: @Saftkeks Simply re-clone your repo and check again your config.

Comment: `fatal: destination path 'projectname' already exists and is not an empty directory.` I deleted the folder before and cloned it again, that doesn't do the job either. Do I have to add the project as a remote?

Comment: @Saftkeks Sure, clone again, but add a new folder name at the end of the clone command

Comment: FINALLY that worked. I wonder why, but I won't question it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't and it's unnessary to `git init` before `git clone`, which would make a nested git repo. `git init` turns the current folder into a git repo, and `git clone` makes another git repo inside the current folder.

Comment: Uhm I can see what you're saying, I have two .git folders now. But would that solve my problem?